# communication between Tweak and app

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia, tweak

I have a *Tweak* and an app.  The tweak is used to block SMS and the app is used to show the blocked SMS.  But I don't know how to send the blocked SMS from the tweak to the app.

How can I do this?

Comment: `CPDistributedMessagingCenter`...

Comment: Right,I am trying it.

Comment: CPDistributedMessagingCenter works for you? i also tried same thing but won't work.it show error on device console "deny mach-register com.mycompany.myCenter"

Comment: @priyanka May be your app is in sandbox. The rocketbootstrap will be useful for you.Sorry for so~~~~~ late answer.